# AS3 Display list and box2d

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d, displaylist

I have a function called "brick" inside a subclass called createBrick that extends from the sprite class, also I have a movie clip created in the library exported for runtime sharing called "Brick".  For some odd reason when I run the code the brick is not showing up on the stage even though it does get created when I debug the code.

here is the function

```
     public  class createBrick extends Sprite {

        public function createBrick(_main:Main) {
                    main = _main; 
                    var go:Brick = new Brick();
                    addChild(go);
                    trace(go.x);
                    brick(475, 235, 30, 30);
        }

    private function brick(pX: int, pY: int, w: Number, h: Number): void {

                var bric:Brick = new Brick();
                addChild(bric);
                bric.x = pX;
                bric.y = pY;
                bric.width = w;
                bric.height = h;

                var polygonShape: b2PolygonShape = new b2PolygonShape();
                var polygonFixture: b2FixtureDef = new b2FixtureDef();
                polygonShape.SetAsBox(w / 2 / worldScale, h / 2 / worldScale);
                polygonFixture.shape = polygonShape;
                polygonFixture.density = .2;
                polygonFixture.restitution = 0.9;
                polygonFixture.friction = 0.9;
                var brickbodyDef: b2BodyDef = new b2BodyDef();
                brickbodyDef.type=b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;
                brickbodyDef.userData = bric;
                brickbodyDef.position.Set(bric.x / worldScale, bric.y / worldScale);
                var theBrick: b2Body = world.CreateBody(brickbodyDef);
                theBrick.CreateFixture(polygonFixture);
                }
        }
```

The same function works perfectly if I have all the code with in the main document class and I do see a brick on the stage.  Any clues Am I not referencing it properly?

Comment: `I have a brick class that extends from the Main document class ` Why are you extending your document class?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo it's an extension of the Sprite class

Comment: Not enough information is given.

Comment: I just added more info, does this make sense?

Comment: By the name used I'm guessing you are using the "createBrick" class as some type of factory and so again I'm guessing you never actually add an instance of createBrick anywhere.

Comment: I am passing a reference to createBrick from the main document class  though movie clip "Brick" never gets assigned or mapped per say on the bricks if I create its instances at the createBrick  class level. ( I do see the bricks image if I init it with in the  Main.as document class

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, just had to pass the stage reference from main document class for the sprite to show up.

Comment: it's easier to simply add the instance of the Brick class from where you instantiate it instead of having the object add itself to some container.