# lost with the objects not displaying in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d

I have a class that is suppose to create bricks on stage. every thing seems to be working fine with no errors and I can even see the brick objects created and collision variables getting initialized in the debugger window but  still nothing shows up on the stage, Any help would be greatly appreciated I have spent hours to figure out what I have missed  but to no avail  :(

Here is the code

```
public class Level1 extends Sprite {

    private var worldVar:world = new world();
    public var stageRef:Stage;

    public function Level1(stageRef:Stage) {


        stageRef = stageRef;

        brick(402,431,140,36, stageRef);
        brick(544,431,140,36,stageRef);
        brick(342,396,16,32,stageRef);
        brick(604,396,16,32,stageRef);
        brick(416,347,16,130,stageRef);
        brick(532,347,16,130,stageRef);
        brick(474,273,132,16,stageRef);
        brick(474,257,32,16,stageRef);
        brick(445,199,16,130,stageRef);
        brick(503,199,16,130,stageRef);
        brick(474,125,58,16,stageRef);
        brick(474,100,32,32,stageRef);
        brick(474,67,16,32,stageRef);
        brick(474,404,64,16,stageRef);
        brick(450,363,16,64,stageRef);
        brick(498,363,16,64,stageRef);
        brick(474,422,64,16,stageRef);
    }

    private function brick(pX: int, pY: int, w: Number, h: Number, _stg:Stage): void {
        var sg = _stg; // assign the stage 
        var bric:Sprite = new Brick();
        sg.addChild(bric);
        //trace(worldVar.m_sprite.);
        bric.x = pX;
        bric.y = pY;
        bric.width = w;
        bric.height = h;

        var polygonShape: b2PolygonShape = new b2PolygonShape();
        var polygonFixture: b2FixtureDef = new b2FixtureDef();
        polygonShape.SetAsBox(w / 2 / worldVar.worldScale, h / 2 / worldVar.worldScale);
        polygonFixture.shape = polygonShape;
        polygonFixture.density = 1;
        polygonFixture.restitution = 0.5;
        polygonFixture.friction = 0.9;
        var brickbodyDef: b2BodyDef = new b2BodyDef();
        //brickbodyDef.type=b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;
        brickbodyDef.userData = bric;
        brickbodyDef.position.Set(pX / worldVar.worldScale, pY / worldVar.worldScale);
        var theBrick: b2Body = worldVar.createWorld.CreateBody(brickbodyDef);
        theBrick.CreateFixture(polygonFixture);


    }


}
```

> Based on @null recommendation    I did make changes to my document
>   class

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.*;
import Levels.Level1;
import world;

public class Main extends Sprite {

    public var worldVar:world = new world();
    public var bird: birdMc = new birdMc();
    //public var bric:Brick = new Brick();
    public var level:Levels.Level1 = new Levels.Level1();

    public function Main() {

    var bg: backgroundMc = new backgroundMc();

        addChild(worldVar.m_sprite);
        worldVar.m_sprite.addChild(bg);
        worldVar.m_sprite.addChild(bird);
        worldVar.m_sprite.addChild(level);

    }
}
```

}

everything gets rendered on the stage perfectly **Thanks for that**  but now I 'm stuck with no box2d physics applied to the bricks though  all the collisions working perfectly for the bird on the same stage.

> Here is the code for birdMC class

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.Stage;
import Box2D.Dynamics.*;
import Box2D.Collision.*;
import Box2D.Collision.Shapes.*;
import Box2D.Common.Math.*;
import Box2D.Dynamics.Joints.*;
import world;
import Levels.*;


public class birdMc extends MovieClip {

    public var worldVar:world = new world();
    //public var m:Main = new Main();
    //public var sleep: Boolean = true;
    // public var main:Main; // use this variable to access objects declared with in the main class
    //public var stageRef:Stage;// use this variabel to access the main the stage

    public function birdMc() {



        //this.stageRef = worldVar.m_sprite;
        this.x = worldVar.birdPlacementX;
        this.y = worldVar.birdPlacementY;
        this.buttonMode = true;

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateWorld);
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, birdClicked);
        // constructor code
    }


    private function birdClicked(e: MouseEvent): void {

        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, birdMoved);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, birdReleased);
        this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, birdClicked);
    }
    private function birdMoved(e: MouseEvent): void {

        this.x = worldVar.m_sprite.mouseX;
        this.y = worldVar.m_sprite.mouseY;
        var distanceX: Number = this.x - worldVar.birdPlacementX;
        var distanceY: Number = this.y - worldVar.birdPlacementY;
        if (distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY > 1000) {
            var birdAngle: Number = Math.atan2(distanceY, distanceX);
            this.x = worldVar.birdPlacementX + 100 * Math.cos(birdAngle);
            this.y = worldVar.birdPlacementY + 100 * Math.sin(birdAngle);
        }
    }
    private function birdReleased(e: MouseEvent): void {

        this.buttonMode = false;
        removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, birdMoved);
        removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, birdReleased);
        var sphereShape: b2CircleShape = new b2CircleShape(15 / worldVar.worldScale); // define the shape with the radius
        var sphereFixture: b2FixtureDef = new b2FixtureDef(); // define the fixture
        sphereFixture.density = 1;
        sphereFixture.friction = 6;
        sphereFixture.restitution = 0.5;
        sphereFixture.shape = sphereShape; // glue the shape to fixture
        var sphereBodyDef: b2BodyDef = new b2BodyDef(); // create a body
        sphereBodyDef.type = b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;
        sphereBodyDef.userData = this; // attaching our moviclip to the body
        sphereBodyDef.position.Set(this.x / worldVar.worldScale, this.y / worldVar.worldScale);
        worldVar.birdSphere = worldVar.createWorld.CreateBody(sphereBodyDef);
        worldVar.birdSphere.CreateFixture(sphereFixture);
        var distanceX: Number = this.x - worldVar.birdPlacementX;
        var distanceY: Number = this.y - worldVar.birdPlacementY;
        var distance: Number = Math.sqrt(distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY);
        var birdAngle: Number = Math.atan2(distanceY, distanceX);
        worldVar.birdSphere.SetLinearVelocity(new b2Vec2(-distance * Math.cos(birdAngle) / 2, -distance * Math.sin(birdAngle) / 2));
    }

    public function updateWorld(e: Event): void {

        var velIterations: int = 10; // times velocity of objects get updated
        var posIterations: int = 10; // adjusts positions to avoid overlap
        worldVar.createWorld.Step(worldVar.timeStep, velIterations, posIterations); // setup the bodies in the world update speed  10, 10 is a safe number
        for (var currentBody: b2Body = worldVar.createWorld.GetBodyList(); currentBody; currentBody = currentBody.GetNext()) {
            if (currentBody.GetUserData()) {
                currentBody.GetUserData().x = currentBody.GetPosition().x * worldVar.worldScale;
                currentBody.GetUserData().y = currentBody.GetPosition().y * worldVar.worldScale;
                currentBody.GetUserData().rotation = currentBody.GetAngle() * (180 / Math.PI);
            }
        }
        worldVar.createWorld.ClearForces(); // clear forces to let the simulation start again
        worldVar.createWorld.DrawDebugData();

    }

}
```

}

> Here is the world class I primarily use it to declare global variables
>   and to add walls with in the b2 world.

```
package  {
import Box2D.Dynamics.*;
import Box2D.Collision.Shapes.*;
import Box2D.Common.Math.*;

import flash.display.Sprite;

public class world {

    public var gravity: b2Vec2 = new b2Vec2(0, 9.81); // define gravity
    public var createWorld: b2World = new b2World(gravity, true); // add gravity and put to sleep if not active to true
    public var worldScale: int = 30; // convert meters into pixels
    public var birdSphere: b2Body;
    public var timeStep = 1 / 60;
    public var birdPlacementX = 210; 
    public var birdPlacementY = 325;
    public var m_sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();

    public function world() {

        addWall(800, 10, 0, 490);  //floor
        addWall(800, 10, 0, -5);// ceiling
        addWall(10, 600, 0, 0); // left
        addWall(10, 600, 800, 0); // right

    }

    private function addWall(w, h, px, py): void {
        var floorShape: b2PolygonShape = new b2PolygonShape();
        floorShape.SetAsBox(w / worldScale, h / worldScale);
        var floorFixture: b2FixtureDef = new b2FixtureDef();
        floorFixture.density = 0;
        floorFixture.friction = 10;
        floorFixture.restitution = 0.2;
        floorFixture.shape = floorShape;
        var floorBodyDef: b2BodyDef = new b2BodyDef();
        floorBodyDef.position.Set(px / worldScale, py / worldScale);
        var floor: b2Body = createWorld.CreateBody(floorBodyDef);
        floor.CreateFixture(floorFixture);

    }

}
```

}

the problem is  the bird and the wall collision works perfectly but not the bricks that's what is confusing for me, although they are all instantiated separately  as

```
public var createWorld: b2World = new b2World(gravity, true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here. I'd go as far and say that they are the two most common anti patterns used in AS3.

- **Passing a reference to stage to a `DisplayObject`** It makes little to no sense, because every `DisplayObject` has its
  own reference to stage in the `.stage` property. Why create yet
  another class member to reference `stage`?

  The special thing about this property is that it is `null` as long as
  the object is not on the display list. As soon as the object is
  added, `stage` will become a valid reference. If a class that extends
  `DisplayObject` needs a reference to `stage` that's valid, simply
  listen for the `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` Event, which will be dispatched
  as soon as the object is added and `stage` becomes valid.
- **Adding anything to `stage`** as one can read [in the documentation of `addChild()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChild%28%29), adding something to `stage` is something one shouldn't do.

  > So, generally, objects should not be added to the Stage, directly, at all.

That's good. Because if nothing should be added to `stage`, there's no need to pass a reference to `stage` in the first place, which solves the first problem.

If it shouldn't be added to `stage`, what else should it be added to?
The answer to that is: the main time line or a `DisplayObjectContainer` that you create yourself.

On the main timeline, you instantiate a `Level1` (horrible class name btw!) object and add it to the display list:

```
var level:Level1 = new Level1();
addChild(level);
```

`Level1` `extends` `DisplayObjectContainer`, which means that things can be added to it. In your case, all the bricks of that level should be added to the level. the level acts as a container for all he content of the level.

I modified the existing code:

```
public class Level1 extends Sprite 
{
    private var worldVar:world = new world();

    public function Level1() 
    {
        brick(402,431,140,36);
        brick(544,431,140,36);
        brick(342,396,16,32);
        brick(604,396,16,32);
        brick(416,347,16,130);
        brick(532,347,16,130);
        brick(474,273,132,16);
        brick(474,257,32,16);
        brick(445,199,16,130);
        brick(503,199,16,130);
        brick(474,125,58,16);
        brick(474,100,32,32);
        brick(474,67,16,32);
        brick(474,404,64,16);
        brick(450,363,16,64);
        brick(498,363,16,64);
        brick(474,422,64,16);
    }

    private function brick(pX: int, pY: int, w: Number, h: Number): void 
    {
        var brick:Sprite = new Brick();

        addChild(brick); //not adding to stage, but the Level1 instance

        //trace(worldVar.m_sprite.);
        brick.x = pX;
        brick.y = pY;
        brick.width = w;
        brick.height = h;

        var polygonShape: b2PolygonShape = new b2PolygonShape();

        var polygonFixture: b2FixtureDef = new b2FixtureDef();
        polygonShape.SetAsBox(w / 2 / worldVar.worldScale, h / 2 / worldVar.worldScale);
        polygonFixture.shape = polygonShape;
        polygonFixture.density = 1;
        polygonFixture.restitution = 0.5;
        polygonFixture.friction = 0.9;

        var brickBodyDef: b2BodyDef = new b2BodyDef();
        //brickBodyDef.type=b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;
        brickBodyDef.userData = bric;
        brickBodyDef.position.Set(pX / worldVar.worldScale, pY / worldVar.worldScale);

        var brickBody: b2Body = worldVar.createWorld.CreateBody(brickBodyDef);
        brickBody.CreateFixture(polygonFixture);
    }
}
```

The rule of thumb is: DisplayObjects never add themselves to the display list and they only add other children to themselves.

This provides a strict hierarchical structure (like a tree) that makes it clear how adds whom and how to the display. For sure, this rule of thumb will not hold for every situation, but for the most part, in such basic situations, it should work fine.

---

> but now I 'm stuck with no box2d physics applied to the bricks though all the collisions working perfectly for the bird on the same stage

The problem is that each individual element creates a new instance of the `world` class. I have no idea what this class is doing, as box2d's world class is actually named [`b2World`](http://www.box2dflash.org/docs/2.1a/reference/Box2D/Dynamics/b2World.html#CreateController%28%29). I suppose you created some kind of wrapper class for the `b2World` class, as per this line in `Level1`:

```
worldVar.createWorld.CreateBody(brickbodyDef);
```

But all the involved class that I have seen so far, create their own instance of that class:

```
public var worldVar:world = new world();
```

The above line can be found in both `birdMC` and `Level1`. So they live in their own worlds, separate from each other.

The core of the problem is the same as in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31787731/as3-display-list-and-box2d):
**You need a world object to create bodies.**
This is very different from As3, where you can create the object and later decide where you want to add it to.

One solution would be to pass the world as a parameter to each constructor. Just the way you did it with `stage` previously. That will allow you to create one single world and pass it to all constructors, which in turn create their box2d body objects on the same world.

Comment: I made those changes Please see above  now am stuck with no box2d physics

Comment: @Adeel I made some assumptions and edited my post, to address this problem

Comment: Thank for your prompt replies I really appreciate it.  I edited my post to add the wall.as  class this will give you a better understanding of what I am missing .  Thank you again for your help

Comment: @Adeel as I suspected, there are different b2 world objects created. As the `world` class creates the walls, every world object comes with walls. That's why the collisions between bird and walls works. The collisions between walls and bricks would also work (if there were any), because the world of the bricks also has its walls. As I wrote in my edit: the solution is to pass the `world` object to all those classes instead of letting them create their own.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help this problem has haunted me for I don't know how long but now it works like charm thanks to you.